# How to look dynamically for a keyword in all columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to be able to look dynamically for a specific keyword in all columns of a table. The purpose of the script would be to only have to change the keyword and the table name, without needing to know what are all the columns of the table.

That means that the following code is not a satisfying solution :

[...] WHERE 'keyword' IN (field1, field2, field3, field4, ...) [...]

I was able to retrieve all the column names of a table dynamically using a subquery. But then, a IN statement in that subquery returns an empty result.

Then, I created a new subquery that returns the list of columns in a comma-separated list format. But the result is also empty.

Here is the script so far :

```
DECLARE @DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @KEYWORD VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @QUERY01 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QUERY02 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SUBQUERY01 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SUBQUERY02 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DATABASE_NAME = '[xxx]'
SET @SCHEMA_NAME = '[dbo]'
SET @TABLE_NAME = 'tblCustomers'
SET @KEYWORD = 'Jean'

SET @SUBQUERY01 = 'SELECT Name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = (SELECT 
object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''')'
SET @SUBQUERY02 = 'SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT '', '' + Name FROM 
sys.columns WHERE object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE 
name = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + ''') FOR XML PATH('''')), 2, 1000000)'

SET @QUERY01 = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DATABASE_NAME + '.' + @SCHEMA_NAME + 
'.' + @TABLE_NAME
-- + ' WHERE ''' + @KEYWORD + ''' IN (FirstName, LastName)' -- Works                    
+ ' WHERE ''' + @KEYWORD + ''' IN (' + @SUBQUERY01 + ')'

SET @QUERY02 = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @DATABASE_NAME + '.' + @SCHEMA_NAME + 
'.' + @TABLE_NAME
+ ' WHERE ''' + @KEYWORD + ''' IN (' + @SUBQUERY02 + ')'

EXEC (@SUBQUERY01)  -- OK (List of column names, one per row)
EXEC (@SUBQUERY02)  -- OK (List of column names, comma-separated values)

EXEC (@QUERY01)     -- NOK (Empty result)
EXEC (@QUERY02)     -- NOK (Empty result)
```

I would expect the script to return all rows that contain the keyword in one of the columns. For example, the following code works fine :

```
SELECT * FROM [xxx].[dbo].tblCustomers
WHERE 'Jean' IN (FirstName, LastName)
```

Comment: Careful, this is very open to injection, You should be quoting your object, and parametrising your parameters in dynamic SQL.

Comment: add a `print @QUERY01` and verify the query

Comment: You need to check data types also or numeric columns will fail.

Comment: You are adding `@SUBQUERY01` text instead of it's result to `@QUERY01`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably what you're after. Note i limit the search to only look in columns that are string types, properly quote your objects (using `QUOTENAME`) and parametrise the statement:

```
DECLARE @Schema sysname,
        @Table sysname,
        @Keyword varchar(100);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Schema = N'dbo';
SET @Table = N'icp_yyclient';
SET @Keyword = 'Smith';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'WHERE @Keyword IN (' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(C.[name])
                                           FROM sys.columns c
                                                JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                                                JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                                                JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                                            WHERE t.[name] = @Table
                                              AND s.[name] = @Schema
                                              AND ct.[name] IN (N'varchar',N'char',N'nvarchar',N'nchar',N'sysname')
                                            FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N');';
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Keyword varchar(100)', @Keyword;
```